# RaspPi and DYMO LabelWriter, CUPS driver, landscape orientation

Tags: pi-3, printing, cups

Did anybody win the struggle to install a DYMO LabelWriter 450 on RaspBian successful (presumably using apache2 and CUPS for external configuration) ?

And did anybody print landscape orientated labels, e.g. with type 11354 (57x32mm labels) ?

On installation process of the driver I saw a lot of error messages running over the terminal, in the steps `make` and `make install`, but regardless these messages the installation finished normal and the printer is available, including printing a test page and setting preferences etc.

And the printer accepts jobs, but never in landscape modus. The print file is a small .pdf file or a .png image file, both formatted to 56x31mm (this is what I used to print successful on debian on a 64bit machine as well as on Mac OSX / Apple Mac mini, used as server)

The RaspPi should do the print job according this script:
`wget -O /app/print/label.pdf http://**myserver**/0a4.pdf && lp -d DYMO -o landscape /app/print/label.pdf` 
or this one
`wget -O /app/print/label.pdf http://**myserver**/0a4.pdf && lp -d DYMO -o orientation-requested=4 /app/print/label.pdf` 
but with no success.

On the regular linux or Apple server (not RaspPi) the driver decided by itself, whether to print in landscape or portrait, if possible, without setting any print option for this.

Any suggestions anybody ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't dive deeper into it, but the problem seems to be with RaspBian only.
After I installed Ubuntu and minibian (which I use since then), the DYMO driver works as expected.

Comment: BTW, minibian is my 1st choice from now on. Fast and slack, ready to install only necessary packages.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: I guess that raspbian drivers somehow decides that orientation should always be portrait (i.e. if wifht > height, it transposes the image). At least that's what I observe. Unfortunately, I am not ready to switch distro

Answer (score 0):

On a B+, with Raspbian Jessie (lite install) and CUPS 1.7.5 installed, connecting a DYMO LabelWriter 400 to the USB and rebooting, the DYMO was available straight away, within the CUPS remote server admin application. I did not need to install any DYMO software on the pi manually.  I used the Bonjour  printer wizard from a windows 10 client to discover the printer on my home LAN.  The only wrinkle was I installed it initially as a generic text printer, then afterwards used the windows dialogue to change it to the correct DYMO driver.  I had previously installed the DYMO software V8.5.3 on my windows client.

Regarding the difficulty printing landscape, reading the [dymo SDK support blog was useful](http://developers.dymo.com/2010/06/15/label-printing-and-web-deployment/).  Rather than trying from outside of the DYMO Label software, create a layout or static label and print that successfully.  Then the layout can be used as a template (see comments on link).